# Shopware: Plugin implemented only on responsive theme

Tags: plugins, shopware

I have lately installed a Google Tag Manager plugin on our Shopware store, the problem is that it is only implemented on the Responsive theme.

We have created another theme, which is derived from Responsive but has another name.

How can I make the plugin work for this theme as well (or instead)?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, maybe it is not derived from Responsive...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `protected $injectBeforePlugins =  true;` in your theme's `Theme.php` file.